# Почему использование !important крайне не желательно?

Tags: css

Почему использование !important крайне не желательно в CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При добавлении `!important` к значению стилевого свойства его важность повышается. Если переопределить значение того же свойства без `!important`, оно будет игнорироваться браузерами. Т.е. можно "перебить" только тем же `!important`.

[Изучаем матчасть](http://htmlbook.ru/css/!important)

Существуют редкие допущения. К примеру, в Twitter bootstrap `!important` имеется у [глобальных/атомарных css-классов `.hide` и `.show`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/49519e981614fb8e0c4fabcbb0a632db292c2b3c/less/utilities.less#L26).

В общем, что-то из серии "отстрелить себе ногу" или тому, кто будет после вас верстать.

Стоит заметить, что семейству IE < 7 по барабану, но кто о покойниках уже вспоминает.

Comment: Как дополнение к данному ответу, вставлю свои пять копеек:
Я бы не был так категоричен. В некоторых случаях можно и нужно использовать !important, но при правильном написании стилей, его использование можно избежать. Отвечая на вопрос: использование !important нарушает нормальную иерархию применения стилей и это затрудняет отладку.